# Error while compiling a C++ program with G++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

v This is `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it, I go into cmd and type `g++ main.cpp` but it gives me 2 errors, saying that both `cout` and `endl` aren't declared. I can only imagine that it's because it can't find the namespace `std` or can't include `<stdio.h>`. How would I make this work?

Comment: You should use #include <iostream> instead of <stdio.h>

Comment: You forgot `#include <iostream>`

Comment: I've made a similar mistake when I first started learning C++ right after C.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include `iostream`, not `stdio.h` to use `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

Comment: It works, but I can't accept an answer yet (I have to wait 12 minutes)